# vueJS table with dynamic data

Tags: api, vue.js, visual-web-developer

I am trying to populate a table using bootStrap and vueJS using an API return from harry potter API. I can see the data is being returned but it does not show up on my DOM. I have a component called `HouseRoster` which I would like to deploy to create the tables for different houses.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HouseRoster
      house="Gryffindor"
      fields="fields"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import HouseRoster from '@/components/HouseRoster.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    HouseRoster
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fields: [
        'name',
        'role',
        'bloodStatus',
        'species'
      ],
      characters: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    const house = 'Gryffindor'
    const url = 'https://www.potterapi.com/v1/characters?key=key&house=' + house
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'get'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        this.characters = jsonData
      })
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'Gryffindor'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are storing data in characters array, and i can't see you are using it anywhere.

Comment: It should be able to infer it from the fields I thought. as it can figure out the header that way. How would you approach it?